Make the bridging part smoother

This is the initial bridging appearance, and it can be seen that the bridging part between the two blue lines is directly connected.
By adjusting the parameters, the bridged part can be made smoother.
50% smooth

100% smooth

Are there any tools or modifiers in Blender that can achieve similar effects？

Do you want the result to be just curved like in the answer by @joshsanfelici or should it bulge outwards or to the front like in your reference images?

thanks a lot, it looks like bulge outward and make it smooth @GordonBrinkmann

In my example I had two edge loops with the same amount of vertices.
I added a third edgeloop (same amount).

Used Ctrl E > Bridge edge loop to connect two selected edgeloops. Repeated for the third.

Used Ctrl R to add some more edgeloops, then select the three original loops (thoose which will have to be unaffected by the procedure).

Enable Built-In LoopTools AddOn, and press the Curve Button.


Why bother to create several loop cuts above and below the center loop? Just select it and use Ctrl+B to bevel the edge with the Width Type set to Percent.

Results are not the same, some curved surfaces are impossible to achieve with Bevel only, Curve tool adds lot more control.

No, of course they are not the same, never said that. But for one there was no specific shape given, it only says "smooth", and depending on how you create the central loop and probably using a custom profile you can modify the shape resulting from the Bevel tool a lot, too. And you could - instead of beveling in Edit Mode - use a Bevel modifier and tweak the settings until you are satisfied. Surely the Curve tool has it's advantages too and as you said, some curved surfaces may not be achievable with the Bevel tool.

Make sure you have the LoopTools addon enabled. You can do a simple smoothly curved transition like in the other answer also with the Bevel tool, and in addition to that you can modify it even more by doing the following if you have two edge loops with the same amount of vertices:


Select both edge loops and right-click for the context menu. Choose LoopTools > Bridge.


After bridging the loops, use the Loop Cut and Slide tool with Ctrl+R to create a loop cut in the center.


Now with the new loop selected make adjustments of how you want the result to look like "bulge-wise". Scale it up or down, move or rotate it - whatever.


Then press Ctrl+B to enable the Bevel tool. By default it uses the Width Type > Offset which will not look very good, so it does not really matter how many segments you create or how far you bevel it. Just confirm the bevel by left-clicking.


Open up the tool options at the bottom left of the viewport. Switch the Width Type to Percent and enter a Width Percent value to your liking. You can also change the Segments now if you want something else than what you did in the previous step.


By default the Bevel tool's Profile Type is set to Superellipse, which should give you a simple smooth transition. But if you want you can change it to Custom and create your own profile:



By the way, using Bevel you do not have to do it destructively. Give the central loop under Edges Data a Mean Bevel Weight of 1 in Edit Mode, then add a Bevel modifier to the object and set it to Limit Method > Weight and as described above the Width Type > Percent.
Now you can tweak the settings, give it a custom profile and play along with it until you like the result. Or in Edit Mode change the location, rotation and size of the central loop to change the overall shape.

$$\Downarrow$$

